# Android: Rename database filename?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rename, dbflow

I have an existing database with the app name without ".db" extension at the end. Now the database created with [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow) library adds ".db" extension at the end. How can specify that it shouldn't add the ".db" extension when creating database.
Or
If It can't do that then please tell me a way so that I can rename my existing database to have a ".db" extension before DBFlow creates the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I tried following code and it worked.

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath("db_name");
boolean renamed = dbFile.renameTo(new File(getDatabasePath("db_name").getParent(), "db_name.db"));
Log.d("Renamed", renamed+"");
```

Logcat outputs `true`
And I checked by using adb shell and it did work. If there is someother way to do it please add it.